# How to Terminate a JavaScript XMLHttpRequest when the browser goes offline

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible to terminate an ajax request incase the browser goes offline?
In that when the browser connection is offline, the request is cancelled and a message is displayed  prompting the user to check their internet connection
This is my sample code:

```js
function view() {
  'use strict';
  const again = '<br><b>Time out, please check your Internet connectioin or' +
    ' <br><a id=\'try2\'>RETRY</a></b>';
  const n = document.getElementById('clas2').value;
  const cempt = '<br><b>Please select a class</b>';
  const loader = '<div class=\'lds-ellipsis\'><div></div>' +
    '<div></div><div></div><div></div></div>';
  try {
    if ('' === n) {
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = cempt;
    } else {
      const e = new XMLHttpRequest();
      e.timeout = 3e4;
      e.onload = function() {
        const a = this.responseText;
        if (a.indexOf('done') > -1) {
          document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = this.responseText;
        } else if (a.indexOf('error') > -1) {
          document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = this.responseText;
          document.getElementById('r2').style.color = 'blue';
          document.getElementById('r2').addEventListener('click', view, false);
        } else {
          document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      e.open('GET', '../viewuser/view.php?clas=' + n, true);
      e.ontimeout = function() {
        document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = again;
        document.getElementById('try2').style.color = 'blue';
        document.getElementById('try2').addEventListener('click', view, false);
      };
      e.send();
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = loader;
    }
  } catch (err) {
    document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = err;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I just found the solution

```
 e.onerror=function(){
      document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = 'you are offline';
  }
```